# Where does this form redirect?

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I am new to posting on this site and PHP...I am trying to jump in on this site and make some updates. I don't see any redirect after the form is submitted. I was going to add an action, but don't want to cause and error. Can someone please lead me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/meta'); ?>
<script>
    function varifyForm(){
        if(document.getElementById('terms').checked == false){
            alert('Please Accept Terms and Conditions');
            return false;
        }else if(document.getElementById('privacy').checked == false){
            alert('Please Accept Privacy Policy');
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------->
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<!--------------------------------HEADER-------------------------------------------> 

<!--------------------------------BODY------------------------------------------->
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="full" style="margin:15px 0;">
      <h2 align="center">Registration – Member</h2>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" onSubmit="return varifyForm()">
            <?php
                if( $this->session->flashdata('error_msg') != ''){
            ?>
            <p style="font-weight:bold; color:#F00;"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error_msg'); ?></p>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            <?php
                if( $this->session->flashdata('success_msg') != ''){
            ?>
            <p style="font-weight:bold; color:#0F0;"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg'); ?></p>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="terms[first_name]" value="<?php if($this->session->flashdata('first_name') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('first_name')); } ?>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="terms[last_name]" value="<?php if($this->session->flashdata('last_name') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('last_name')); } ?>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Cell Phone No:</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="" name="terms[phone_no]" value="<?php if($this->session->flashdata('phone_no') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('phone_no')); } ?>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" name="terms[email]" value="<?php if($this->session->flashdata('email') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('email')); } ?>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="" name="password" value="" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="" name="confirm_password" value="" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Address:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="terms[address]"><?php if($this->session->flashdata('address') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('address')); } ?></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">City:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="terms[city]" value="<?php if($this->session->flashdata('city') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('city')); } ?>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">State:</label>
                <select name="terms[state]" class="form-control" >
                  <option value="" selected="selected">State / Province</option>
                  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                  <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                  <option value="California">California</option>
                  <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                  <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                  <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                  <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
                  <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                  <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                  <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                  <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                  <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                  <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                  <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                  <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                  <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                  <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                  <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                  <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                  <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                  <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                  <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                  <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                  <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                  <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                  <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                  <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                  <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                  <option value="New York">New York</option>
                  <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                  <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                  <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                  <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                  <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                  <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                  <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                  <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                  <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                  <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                  <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                  <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                  <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                  <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                  <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                  <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                  <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                  <option value="Armed Forces Americas">Armed Forces Americas</option>
                  <option value="Armed Forces Europe">Armed Forces Europe</option>
                  <option value="Armed Forces Pacific">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="terms[zip]" value="<?php if($this->session->flashdata('zip') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('zip')); } ?>" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Your Cause:</label>
                <select name="terms[cause]" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Select A User</option>
                    <?php
                        foreach($causes as $value){
                            $cause_name = $value['nonprofit_name'];
                    ?>  
                            <option value="<?php _e($value['user_id']); ?>" <?php if($this->session->flashdata('cause') != '' AND $this->session->flashdata('cause') == $value['user_id']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>><?php _e($cause_name); ?></option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">How did you hear about this website ?:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="terms[about]"><?php if($this->session->flashdata('about') != ''){ _e($this->session->flashdata('about')); } ?></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Terms and Conditions:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="terms"> I agree to the <a href="<?=base_url() ?>termsandconditions" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Privacy Policy:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="privacy"> I agree to the <a href="<?=base_url() ?>privacypolicy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="btnSignUp" value="signup" class="btn btn-primary"><p style="margin:0;">NEXT</p></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--------------------------------BODY-------------------------------------------> 

<!--------------------------------FOOTER------------------------------------------->
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
<!--------------------------------FOOTER-------------------------------------------> 
<!-- container / end --> 
<!--------------------------------JQUERY-------------------------------------------> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript --> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script>
     new WOW().init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It appears to post to the same page the form is on. If no "action" is present, the default is to post back to the same page it's on. Perhaps the data is actually processed in your header view, or meta, I'm not really sure, I don't see any form handling code.

Comment: For debugging the request add <?PHP var_dump($_POST); ?> to the top of your page and submit the form, you should see an array of items from your form submission; that would indicate your form posts fine and now you can do whatever you wish with the posted data

Comment: Thank you guys. I really appreciate the responses. I will debug and then add an action if nothing comes of it. Again, thanks!